# Xcode build stuck at DataModelCompile `momc`

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have a project which builds fine a month ago. Now I tried to open it again but I am stuck with building the project in Xcode. Upon checking it from the Report Navigator tab, it shows that there was an error on DataModelCompile about a missing inverse property.

I was able to get through this by suppressing the momc warnings in Build Settings. But when I build the project again, I am still stuck at DataModelCompile. This time it doesn't say anything helpful aside from outputting the exact `momc` command.

[image: build stuck at DataModelCompile]

I have tried the following so far but nothing works:

- Clean project and rebuild
- Delete DeriveData folder and rebuild
- Clean, delete DereveData, close Xcode and rebuild
- Remove xcdatamodel, build project, close Xcode, delete DeriveData put back xcdatamodel and rebuild

Please tell me I'm not the only once experiencing this. It is really frustrating that a project that used to work is broken now without anything changed.

Any help is appreciated!

Note:

- I am using the latest version of Xcode (7.1.1)
- The project is using CoreData with 3 versions of xcdatamodel
- I also tried checking out an earlier version of the project but I still encounter the same problem

Comment: I have the same problem. A reboot fixes it temporarily

Comment: Well, it turns out the problem was caused by a png file that I added but is actually a psd file. It's just weird because even if I switch to another version discarding all local changes, the error still don't go away. It was until until several Xcode re-opening and OS X logout that I am able to identify and solve the real problem. And the error message is very helpful! T_T